# What is SharingLinkKind.Flexible? and how to use it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, csom, pnp

I have an app that should be able to create all the different types of SharePoint ShareLinks. There is a "Flexible" value in [SharingLinkKind enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharinglinkkind) but it has neither a documentation nor a single example of its usage online.

So what is equivalent to Flexible links via the UI? and how to create one programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

It is used in External Sharing with email address.

[image]

[image]